# Why did Li Hao call himself "foolish"?

Tags: poetry, religion, chinese-language, li-hao

Li Hao's [poem](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/august-2019-chinese-poetry-I-want-to-walk-toward-the-altar-of-the-lord-li) *I Want to Walk Toward the Altar of the Lord* contains the following lines:

> Lord, I am foolish,
> I am suffering, and my body,
>
> like a spoon, here on this earth, sweetly scoops out
> my brain.

Why did the author refer to himself as "foolish"?